# Delete item "WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need a little help please,

Here is my table structure.
Table : 
**Purchase_Master**

```
Purchase_ID | POTYPE | PoNo
     1          M       1
```

Table : **TRN_Purchase_Details**

```
Purchase_Detail_ID |  Purchase_ID |  Head_ID | Item_ID
       1                1               2         3
       2                1               2         3
       3                1               2         3
```

I Pass XML string to SQL for insert, update and delete operation.

**Insert Mode XML string for  @PurchaseDetailsXML**

```
<documentelement>
    <TRN_Purchase_Details>
        <Purchase_Detail_ID> 0</Purchase_Detail_ID>
        <Purchase_ID></Purchase_ID>
        <Head_ID>2</Head_ID>
        <Item_ID>3</Item_ID>
    </TRN_Purchase_Details>
    <TRN_Purchase_Details>
        <Purchase_Detail_ID> 0</Purchase_Detail_ID>
        <Purchase_ID></Purchase_ID>
        <Head_ID>2</Head_ID>
        <Item_ID>3</Item_ID>
    </TRN_Purchase_Details>
    <TRN_Purchase_Details>
        <Purchase_Detail_ID> 0</Purchase_Detail_ID>
        <Purchase_ID></Purchase_ID>
        <Head_ID>2</Head_ID>
        <Item_ID>3</Item_ID>
    </TRN_Purchase_Details>
</documentelement>
```

**Update Mode XML string for @PurchaseDetailsXML**

```
<documentelement>
    <TRN_Purchase_Details>
        <Purchase_Detail_ID>1</Purchase_Detail_ID>
        <Purchase_ID>1</Purchase_ID>
        <Head_ID>2</Head_ID>
        <Item_ID>3</Item_ID>
    </TRN_Purchase_Details>
    <TRN_Purchase_Details>
        <Purchase_Detail_ID>3</Purchase_Detail_ID>
        <Purchase_ID>1</Purchase_ID>
        <Head_ID>2</Head_ID>
        <Item_ID>3</Item_ID>
    </TRN_Purchase_Details>
</documentelement>
```

Here is parsing string of "TRN_Purchase_Details" table :

```
 SELECT  Tbl.Col.value('Purchase_Detail_ID[1]', 'int') AS Purchase_Detail_ID ,                          
                Tbl.Col.value('Purchase_ID[1]', 'int') AS Purchase_ID ,                          
                Tbl.Col.value('Head_ID[1]', 'int') AS Head_ID ,                          
                Tbl.Col.value('Item_ID[1]', 'int') AS Item_ID 
        INTO    #TRN_Purchase_Details                          
        FROM    @PurchaseDetailsXML.nodes('/documentelement/TRN_Purchase_Details') Tbl ( Col )
```

Here is my insert update delete code :

```
MERGE TRN_Purchase_Details MTD                          
                USING                          
                    ( SELECT    Purchase_Detail_ID ,                          
                                Id AS Purchase_ID ,                          
                                Head_ID ,                          
                                Item_ID   
                      FROM      #TRN_Purchase_Details                          
                                LEFT JOIN @ChangeResult ON 1 = 1                          
                    ) AS TMTD                          
                ON MTD.Purchase_Detail_ID = TMTD.Purchase_Detail_ID                          
                    AND MTD.Purchase_ID = TMTD.Purchase_ID           
                WHEN MATCHED THEN                          
                    UPDATE SET MTD.Head_ID = TMTD.Head_ID ,                          
                              MTD.Item_ID = TMTD.Item_ID 

                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN              
                    INSERT ( Purchase_ID ,                          
                             Head_ID ,                          
                             Item_ID
               )                          
                    VALUES ( Purchase_ID ,                          
                             Head_ID ,                          
                             Item_ID                          
                           )  

                            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE   
                             AND   
        MTD.Purchase_Detail_ID NOT IN(SELECT Purchase_Detail_ID FROM #TRN_Purchase_Details)  
                            THEN   
                            DELETE ;
```

**What i want :**

First time i insert 3 entries into "TRN_Purchase_Details".
Second time when i pass 2 entries then delete remaining entry.

My English is poor.

Thanks

Comment: Could you display the example of result set you are expecting? Which rows to be inserted, which entries that you passed on second time, and which rows to be deleted?

Comment: when ever i am in edit mode and delete child entry then it will delete from database. if i have 3 result set in database and want delete 1 entry then i pass only 2 entries set into store procedure and want to delete extra entry that is not matched by source table.

Comment: @AlfinE.R. check question. i update